# SQL Date_Sub syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax

I have been looking at this statement for ages and simply cannot find the error can you guys help?

```
        SELECT XD.*, UhED.row_class,
            (SELECT id
                FROM Comment C
                WHERE C.Excel_Data_Excel_Lists_id = XD.Excel_Lists_id
                    AND C.Excel_Data_row = XD.row
                LIMIT 1
            ) AS has_activity
        FROM User_has_Excel_Lists UhXL
        JOIN Excel_Lists XL
            ON XL.id = UhXL.Excel_Lists_id
        JOIN Excel_Data XD
            ON XD.Excel_Lists_id = XL.id
        LEFT JOIN User_has_Excel_Data UhED
            ON UhED.Excel_Data_Excel_Lists_id = XL.id
                AND UhED.Excel_Data_row = XD.row
                AND UhED.User_id = 1
        WHERE UhXL.User_id = 1
            AND XL.created > DATE_SUB(DATE(now()), INTERVAL 2)<-- it says that the error is here
        GROUP BY XD.telephone 
        ORDER BY last_name ASC, first_name ASC
```

Comment: Is DATE(NOW()) a bit like CURDATE()? And INTERVAL 2 WHAT?

Comment: you should mention the `day or month or year`..`DATE_SUB(DATE(now()), INTERVAL 2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 AND XL.created > DATE_SUB(DATE(now()), INTERVAL 2 DAY)
```

try this it may help you

Answer (score 1):

You forgot do specify the interval **unit** maybe? Something like `INTERVAL 2 DAY` or `INTERVAL 2 HOUR` maybe?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to specify the measure for the interval (e.g., days, months, etc.)

You can check the [syntax for `DATE_SUB` here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_sub.asp)

Answer (score 0):

*if i understand your problem like follow this instructions as:
you should must mention the **day, month, hour, or year** in the following line:*

***your code:***

```
 AND XL.created > DATE_SUB(DATE(now()), INTERVAL 2)
```

***change code: `DAY`***

```
AND XL.created > DATE_SUB(DATE(now()), INTERVAL 2 DAY)
```

*if you are using the `DATE`(tablename) in your table you getting error like:*

***WRONG CODE (sample)(http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5b7e2/7):check the code no:5***

```
SELECT id,DATE_SUB(DAT(NOW()), INTERVAL 2 DAY) 
FROM supportContacts;
```

***RIGHT CODE:***

```
SELECT id,DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 2 DAY) 
FROM supportContacts;
```

***REFER THIS LINK: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5b7e2/7***